# Appying Denning security Model for django admin site

Tags: python, django, access-control, data-security

I wanted to know the procedure of implementing the denning security model for the admin page in django web framework. For this i will have to create subjects and objects. Subjects are users and admin. Objects are appmodels and log entries.
This model should replace the existing permissions setup for a user. How can i program it easily.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, in order to `allow` or `deny` access to specific parts of admin I've been using something like this in my project.

```
#admin.py
    class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = MyModel
            fields = '__all__'

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

            if self.current_user.is_superuser:
                # Do something

            if not self.current_user.is_superuser:
                # Do something else
```